# Athena Date Partition Without Extra Bits

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I have a table with a projected date partition (`p_date`) that I'm trying to insert values into. When i insert values into this table and specify a string value for the `p_date` it complains that I am attempting to insert a varchar into a timestamp column (fair). But when I convert the value to a timestamp and do the same insert it adds an unwanted millis value to the end of the timestamp.

```
-- ERROR varchar cannot be inserted into timestamp
INSERT INTO blah 
(p_date)
VALUES
('2021-01-01 00:00:00');

-- Not error. But adds unwanted `.0` to s3 key
INSERT INTO blah 
(p_date)
VALUES
(timestamp '2021-01-01 00:00:00');
```

Here is what that looks like in S3:

[image: boo]

How can I insert rows into this table at the correct `p_date` partition without changing that field to a string or getting extra bits on the end?

Comment: Can you share the DDL used to create this table?

Answer (score 0):

Does your partition key have the type `TIMESTAMP`? In that case Athena will format the values as it formats timestamps. If you want it to format them as dates you can use the `DATE` type instead.